# Can I disable "route rendering optimization" in the Bing Maps AJAX Control?

Tags: bing-maps

I'm trying to draw many overlapping polygons that are shaped like rectangles with rounded corners (we sometimes refer to them as "sausage links"). They are actually created by slicing up an existing line and buffering the slices.

They look fine on Google Maps, however Bing's "[route rendering optimization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd807493.aspx)" make them look awful. I assume they do this for performance reasons, but I am careful not to display too many of them at one time, and even zoomed all the way in they do not look right (still too jagged).

Is it possible to disable this feature? I'm using version 6.3.

I can't change the underlying data, they need to be this shape, and the geometry is already simplified as much as possible while allowing them to still look rounded (Douglas–Peucker-ized to 1 meter).

[image: Zoom level 16]

[image: Zoom level 17]

[image: Zoom level 18]

[image: Zoom level 19]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using v6.3 of the Bing Maps AJAX API, the setting I think you're looking for is:
VEMap.EnableShapeDisplayThreshold(false);

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964367.aspx)

If you're using v7 of the Bing Maps AJAX API, I'm not sure what the equivalent property is, and looking at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/vemapcontroldev/thread/dca3b661-0220-406e-bbdb-8701dba7cbd7 , it seems I'm not the only one...

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention I'm using 6.3, I updated the question to reflect that. It's weird that they don't use the same terminology for this in the two different parts of the documentation, that's why I missed it.